# R Knitr PDF: Is there a posssibility to automatically save PDF reports (generated from .Rmd) through a loop?

Tags: r, pdf, dynamic, report, knitr

I would like to create a loop, which allows me to automatically save PDF reports, which were generated from a **.Rmd** file. For instance, if a variable "ID" has 10 rows, I would like R to automatically save me 10 reports, into a specific directory. These reports shall vary based on the ID selected.

A previous post ([Using loops with knitr to produce multiple pdf reports... need a little help to get me over the hump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396755/using-loops-with-knitr-to-produce-multiple-pdf-reports-need-a-little-help-to)) has dealt with the creation of multiple pdf reports generated from **.Rnw** files. I tried to apply the approach as follows:

````
#Data

```{r, include=FALSE}
set.seed(500)
Score <- rnorm(40, 100, 15)
Criteria1<-rnorm(40, 10, 5)
Criteria2<-rnorm(40, 20, 5)
ID <- sample(1:1000,8,replace=T)
df <- data.frame(ID,Score,Criteria1,Criteria2)

#instead of manually choosing the ID:

subgroup<- subset(df, ID==1) 

# I would like to subset the Data through a loop. My approach was like like this:

for (id in unique(df$ID)){
subgroup<- df[df$ID == id,]}

```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
#Report Analysis

summary(subgroup)
```
#Here will be some text about the summary.



# At the end the goal is to produce automatic pdf reports with the ID name as a filename:

library("rmarkdown")
render("Automated_Report.rmd",output_file = paste('report.', id, '.pdf', sep=''))
````

Comment: You need one loop, not two. The way your code is set up, you loop through all your subgroups, and then when you're done with that you create a bunch of PDFs. You need to combine these: select a subgroup and create a report based on it all within the same loop. If you need more help, you'll have to be a lot more specific than "seems not be working" and probably create a reproducible example.

Comment: You could also look at  `knit_expand` or the `brew` package.

Comment: I have also tried it with only one loop for the subsetting. But that didn't work either. I provided a simple reproducible example, which only pastes the summary for each ID in a report and also exchanged the knit2pdf() function with the render() function from the rmarkdown package.@Gregor

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Adapting your example:

You need one `.rmd` "template" file. It could be something like this, save it as `template.rmd`.

````
This is a subgroup report.

```{r, echo=FALSE}
#Report Analysis
summary(subgroup)
```
````

Then, you need an R script that will load the data you want, loop through the data subsets, and for each subset

1. Define the `subgroup` object used inside the template
2. render the template to the desired output

So, in this *separate script*:

```
# load data 
set.seed(500)
Score <- rnorm(40, 100, 15)
Criteria1<-rnorm(40, 10, 5)
Criteria2<-rnorm(40, 20, 5)
ID <- sample(1:1000,8,replace=T)
df <- data.frame(ID,Score,Criteria1,Criteria2)

library("rmarkdown")

# in a single for loop
#  1. define subgroup
#  2. render output
for (id in unique(df$ID)){
    subgroup <- df[df$ID == id,]
    render("template.rmd",output_file = paste0('report.', id, '.html'))    
}
```

This produced 8 html files in my working directory, each with a summary of a different subset of the data.

Note that this will **not work** if you try clicking the "knit" button inside RStudio, as that runs the R code in a separate R session. However, when you run from the console explicitly using `render` (or `knit2pdf`) the R code in the rmd file still has access to the global environment.

Rather than relying on global variables, another option would be to use [parametrized reports](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html%23parameter_types%2F), defining parameters in the YAML header, and passing the parameter values in as arguments to `rmarkdown::render`.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor this worked! l guess you chose .html because .pdf created an error based on the pandoc output of summary. Since this was anyway just a simple example it did not make a difference in the end.

Comment: Yup, I figured this would be good to work out the general principles, and the details of content would follow easily.