# Create multiple html files R markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

How do I create multiple HTML files in a single R markdown file with the Knit HTML option in RStudio? I want to create a separate HTML file with graphs for different levels of a variable in a data frame. I know a similar question has been posted in [How to best generate multiple HTML files from RMarkdown based on one dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304576/how-to-best-generate-multiple-html-files-from-rmarkdown-based-on-one-dataset), but I do not manage to get this running.

Could someone give me a simple example, for instance to create 3 HTML files of the mtcars dataset for each amount of cylinders.

```
data(mtcars)
for(cyl in unique(mtcars$cyl)){
    plot.data <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl==cyl,]
    plot(plot.data$mpg,plot.data$disp,main=paste(cyl,"cylinders"))
}
```

This would be of great help for me!

Thanks in advance,
Gijs

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to best generate multiple HTML files from RMarkdown based on one dataset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304576/how-to-best-generate-multiple-html-files-from-rmarkdown-based-on-one-dataset)

Comment: Saw that, but I this is not detailed enough for me to get this to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do the job!

The answer to the post [R Knitr PDF: Is there a posssibility to automatically save PDF reports (generated from .Rmd) through a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422008/r-knitr-pdf-is-there-a-posssibility-to-automatically-save-pdf-reports-generate) really helped me.

The render function was the solution.

I thought I had to run this type of markdown just through the Knit HTML button, but then only one HTML file is created. The render function can be used in a for loop in R, calling a template.Rmd file to create multiple HTML files.