# How do I run a loop in Rmarkdown and generate a pdf for every unique value in a column?

Tags: r, loops, r-markdown, knitr

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
ID|Electronic|Nations
1  Panasonic  Japan
2  Yamaha     Japan
3  Sony       Japan
4  Apple      USA
5  Microsoft  USA
6  Samsung    Korea
```

From the dataset there should be 3 PDFs with corresponding plots and adjusted title based on the unique values from column "Nations". As a test we can add the line of code below to see if the pdf is dynamic.

```
table(df$Electronic)
```

Is this possible?

Update**

```
 ---
title: "Electronics"
author: "JW"
date: "8/10/2021"
output:
pdf_document: default
html_document: default
params:
   Nations= Japan
```

---

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

tinytex::install_tinytex()


library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)

df<-tibble(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), Electronic=c("Panasonic","Yamaha","Sony","Apple","Microsoft","Samsung"),
         Nations=c("Japan","Japan","Japan","USA","USA","Korea"))

 lst1 <- split(df, df$Nations)


 render_one <- function(Nations) {
 # assuming the output format of input.Rmd is PDF
 rmarkdown::render(
 'input.Rmd',
 output_file = paste0(Nations, '.pdf'),
 params = list(Nations=lst1),
 envir = parent.frame()
  )
 }

for (Nations in lst1) {
    render_one(taxnum)
  }

#For test
table(df$Nations)
table(df$Nations)
````

```
    Error in abs_path(input) : The file 'input.Rmd' does not exist.
    Calls: <Anonymous> ... render_one -> <Anonymous> -> setwd -> dirname -> 
    abs_path
    Execution halted

    No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF output). 
    You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform: 
    https://www.latex-project.org/get/

    If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R: 
    tinytex::install_tinytex()

    Otherwise consider MiKTeX on Windows - http://miktex.org

    MacTeX on macOS - https://tug.org/mactex/
    (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome _strongly_ recommended)

    Linux: Use system package manager
```

Note that I ran tinytex::install_tinytex() and that when i run an individual report it works when doing a knit.

Comment: Yes it's possible. I expect this will have been answered with other words on this forum already. You might look here for more info: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304576/how-to-best-generate-multiple-html-files-from-rmarkdown-based-on-one-dataset  https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/08/many-reports-from-1-rmarkdown-file/

Comment: I was able to get it. Thank you.